# reledmac : mysterious ways of \autopar

Tags: paragraphs, reledmac

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[parapparatus, noquotation]{reledmac}%
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\usepackage{polyglossia}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%

\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}[%
Script=Devanagari,
Ligatures=TeX,
]
{Adishila}

\newcommand{\MacroA}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\MacroC}[1]{%
    {%
        \centering%
        \textbf{%
            \small{%
                #1%
            }%
        }\par%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\MacroD}[1]{%
    \flushleft%
    {%
%       \pstart%
        \centering%
        \textbf{%
            #1%
        }%
        \par%\pend%
    }%
}%
\newcommand{\MacroE}[2]{#1\footnoteC{#1 - इतिमातृकापाठोसमीचीनः । #2 - इतिपाठः स्यात् ।}}
\newcommand{\MacroF}[1]{\textbf{`#1'}}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{पुस्तकम् अ}%
    \beginnumbering%
    \autopar%
    
    \MacroC{श्रीरस्तु ।}%
    
    \MacroC{श्रीहयशिरसे नमः}%
    
    % Below this doesn't get line number
    \MacroD{%
        सत्यज्ञानानन्दलक्ष्म परिच्छेदविवर्ज्जितम् ।\\
        \MacroE{अस्पृष्टानर्घम्}{अस्पृष्टानर्त्थम्} अनिशमाश्रये नृहरेः पदम् ॥%
    }

    \MacroF{विमतं मित्थ्या , दृश्यत्वात् , यद् इत्थं तत् तथा , यथा सम्प्रतिपन्नम्} ।%
    
    \textbf{न च} --- जगतोऽभावात् आश्रयासिद्धः पक्षः ;\\
    % Below this makes compilation fail, that means it is out of pstart pend
    \edtext{तस्य पारमार्त्थिकत्वाभावेपि}{%
        %\lemma{}%
        \Bfootnote{%
            पारमार्त्थिकत्वावच्छिन्नजगतोसिद्धावपि पारमार्त्थिकत्वस्य पक्षतावच्छेदकत्वाभावत् न आश्रयासिद्धिः पारमार्त्थिकत्वानङ्गीकारमात्रेणापादयितुं शक्यते इत्याशयः ।%
        }%
    }
    
    % A few more lines to show problem
    सत्तामङ्गीकृत्य पुनस्तन्निषेधे \MacroA{परस्य} अपसिद्धान्तश्च ।%\\
    
    %\begin{quoting}% % सत्तामङ्गीकृत्य पुनस्तन्निषेधे \janaH{परस्य} अपसिद्धान्तश्च इत्यस्य परिहारायायासः तन्निरासश्च
    \textbf{पार}मार्त्थिकसत्तात्वमेव निषिद्ध्यते ,
    न तु व्यावहारिकी सत्ता इति चेत् ।%\\%
    
    %\begin{quoting}% पारमार्त्थिकत्वस्य विकल्प्य निरासेन पारमार्त्थिकत्वस्यैव निरासस्य निरासः
    \textbf{किमि}दं पारमार्त्थिकत्वम् ।%\par%
    
    \endnumbering%
\end{document}
```

I was trying to use \autopar of reledmac package to generate \pstart and \pend sections automatically.
It appears that there are some specific ways in which \autopar works. According to the reledmac handbook,

> \autopar fails, however, on paragraphs that start with a { or with any other command that starts a new group before it generates any text. Such paragraphs need to be started explicitly, before the new group is opened, using \indent, \noindent, or \leavemode, or using \pstart itself.

In my example most of line start with some macro which starts a new group for either \centering or bold text, etc. Although, I've not use manual \pstart or \noindent, etc. in above MWE, I implemented them in my project and didn't find anything better.

I observed that MacroC doesn't create any problem, and I got numbered lines.
When I used MacroD, the compilation didn't fail. But, the line didn't get numbered. That hints that the portion is out of \pstart ... \pend. So, \autopar failed there.
And for the same reason, next lines were also out of \pstart ... \pend. Hence when I tried to insert a critical footnote, the compilation failed.

I've a big project where it is happening due to {\bfseries} and my custom commands. Changing {\bfseries} to \textbf{} has solved the problem at some places, but I don't have any clue how. And at some places it didn't affect anything.

I can't produce the big text chunk here, since it may produce aversion in those who are helping here.

Once the present problem is solved and I understand the proper way to use \autopar, I shall try to correct my project and report any related problem in comments.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would say that inserting manullay pstart ... pend would be simplier than trying to understand autopar mechanism, and also more constitente.

Comment: @Maïeul I took a quick look. Did you see that we added para hooks to latex? You find the documentation in ltpara-doc.pdf.

Comment: @Maïeul, Can you confirm that my macros are not the root of this problem? If they are not the root of problem, then I'll accept it as limitation of reledmac and will stick with \pstart ... \pend.

Comment: No, I can't confirm or infirm, as I have no time to look for which macro open or not a start  a new group.